# Trap Flag - Anti-debugging trick

Tags: windows, x86, anti-debugging

I am trying to reverse a program which is employing some kind of anti-debugging trick based on the use of  SEHs and the TF. The code stars with:

[image]

So apparently it's generating an exception with

```
XOR DWORD PTR [ESP], 154h
```

Which ultimately terminates with a call to `ExitProcess()` without even running the program.

I tried using `NOP`s to bypass this but since upon execution the EP is already pointing to this problematic piece of code it did not work.

How can  I bypass this and what's really triggering the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is setting a trap flag with that xor instruction

when it is run normally (not under debugger)

the trap flag is triggered so the handler gets a chance to execute

when the binary is run under debugger the trap flag is ignored 
and the handler doesn't get a chance to execute

hard patch to point to the handler directly or simply change the eip in debugger  for analyzing

your screenshot looks like you are using ollydbg

if so just press shift + f9 after setting a breakpoint at 0x401060  @ the seh handler  that would pass the exception to the program and would bypass the trick

Comment: Most likely this is ollydbg specific behavior.